# Find out which notification is selected in android

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have a chat service in my android application, i generate a notification for every new message tagged by sender's id, so my app can generate multiple notifications

I put sender id to an intent and add that intent to TaskStackBuilder for openning chat activity, if notification is selected, here's my code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, ChatActivity.class);
resultIntent.putExtra(Constants.KEY_CONTACT_ID, message.getSenderId());
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
nBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
Notification notification = nBuilder.build();
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(Constants.KEY_CONTACT_ID, notification);
```

when there is two notifications, i will go to ChatActivity, but the extra that is put to intent, is sender id of first one's notification, not the selected one, how can i get intent of selected notification?

Comment: Try using different notificationId for different notification. Use  >> `mNotificationManager.notify(UNIQUE_ID, notification);`

Comment: i replaced that by token of sender contact (it is unique for each contact), problem not solved